# How associative containers( set, map, multiset and multimap) lookup time is logarithmic ?

Tags: c++

Use binary search to find an element

sorted array:  16 elements

```
1: Compare the key with 8th element  of sorted array.
2: Since memory is contiguous so reaching to the 8th element of sorted array is constant . 
3: Searching of key will continue by making the array half for each iteration  until key is found(or not found) So lookup time in sorted array for any key is logarithmic.
```

Associative container:  16 elements. I am assuming, binary search is used to find an element.

```
1: Compare the key with 8th element  of associative container.
2: Since memory is not contiguous ( node based) , so to find the 8th element , need to iterate this container linearly .
```

1: How the lookup time for associative container is logarithmic ?? Only number of comparisons of elements in associative container is logarithmic ?

I have another question: To locate an element , sorted array always gives better performance than any associative container  ?  Binary search gives only guaranteed logarithmic lookup time for random access iterator?
   Thanks

Comment: You have the template source for whatever implementation you're using; so read it (and be warned: some are easier to read than others). The standard mandates the logarithmic restriction; *how* that is accomplished is left to the implementors.

Comment: ... but generally, they all use some variant of (RB) trees. If trees are balanced, elements lookup is logarithmic, although generally it has more overhead than binary search (both in memory usage for storage and in cache locality when searching, especially for small container size).

Comment: Associative containers you are talking about are ordered, that allows to have log lookup time. That's kind of binary search, only with balanced tree.

Comment: And your second question has an invalid assumption. Sorted arrays and binary search do *not* always have better performance than *any* associative container. An [`unordered_map`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_map), for example, averages *constant time*, again, per the standard.

Comment: "Since memory is not contiguous" doesn't mean that there is no kind of indexing/structure to accelerate the search...

Comment: Also *performance* is not the only reason to use a data-structure. The *rules of the language* forbid you from accidentally disordering your `set`, whereas only your discipline stops you accidentally disordering a `vector` that you wish to `binary_search` in